# Function that checks whether a pair is included in a whitelist?

Tags: algorithm

So say I have a list of "whitelist pairs" like so:

`a | b`
`a | c`
`f | g`

And say I want to write a method like so:

```
function checkIfInWhitelist(itemOne, itemTwo) {
    ...
}
```

Here's the desired functionality:

`checkIfInWhiteList(a, b) // true`

`checkIfInWhitelist(b, a) // true`

`checkIfInWhitelist(b, c) // false`

`checkIfInWhiteList(g, f) // true`

(Basically I want to check if the pair exists in the whitelist)

What's the best and most efficient way to do this?

I was thinking a dictionary where the keys are anything that appears in the whitelist and the values are a list of things that are matched with the key?

For instance, the three whitelist pairs above would map to:

```
a: [b, c]
b: [a]
f: [g]
g: [f]
```

Then, `checkIfInWhitelist` would be implemented like so:

```
function checkIfInWhitelist(itemOne, itemTwo) {
    return map.contains(itemOne) && map[itemOne].contains(itemTwo)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "Efficiency" is a nebulous concept.  In almost all cases, you can make some operations faster at the expense of making others slower.  And you can often trade memory use for speed.  If the goal is fastest possible existence check then I would make a hash or set of [a:b] [b:a] [a:c] [c:a] [f:g] [g:f] so that there is one operation per existence check.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reasonable implementation of hash which works on `std::pair` (such as the one in Boost), and the objects have a fast total order method, then you can do it with a single hash table without artificially doubling the size of the table. Just use a `std::unordered_set` and normalize each pair into non-decreasing order before inserting it. (That is, if a < b, insert std::make_pair(a, b); otherwise insert std::make_pair(b, a).)

Very rough code, missing lots of boilerplate. I should have used perfect forwarding. Not tested.

```
template<typename T> struct PairHash {
  std::unordered_set<std::pair<T, T>> the_hash_;
  using iterator = typename std::unordered_set<std::pair<T, T>>::iterator;
  std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return the_hash_.insert(a < b ? std::make_pair(a, b)
                                  : std::make_pair(b, a));
  }
  bool check(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return the_hash_.end() != the_hash_.find(
             a < b ? std::make_pair(a, b)
                   : std::make_pair(b, a));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Minimal way to do this:**

Have an hashmap with data and what you want to check.

As you want to check an **unsorted pair**, keep an hashmap of *unsorted pair*

**Possible solutions with unsorted datas:**

- Solution A keep a set of two
- Solution B keep the two values in one certain order, but with no meaning. For example, (x,y) => X/Y, and (y,x) => X/Y. 
  you only choose ascendent (or descendent) : X < Y

Solution A takes more space, more time (you have to compare sets).

Solution B needs a little process (order *a*,*b*) but everything else is faster

For checking, you have to pre-process: unorder your data: (*a*,*b*) => *a*,*b* if *a* < *b*, or *b*,*a* if *b* < *a*

**Solution C with sorted datas**

It is longer to pre-process, but (a little faster) to check:

keep every (*a*,*b*), and (*b*,*a*) in your Hashmap: HashMap of List for example (or some implementation of Pair)

So your check is direct. But your first pre-process takes: O(2n . log 2.n) = 2 O(n.log n) + 2 log2 O(n).
So it depends on how many checks you will process after.

As it is very fast to compare and invert *a* and *b*, **I would recommend solution B.**

And if you know the type of your datas (alpha for example), you can store the couple in Strings, like: *a-b*

**your solution is not optimal.**

It combines bad effects of my solutions C and A: 2 embedded Hash collections, and duplicate datas.

And it forgets c:[a] .

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can't possibly do better than O(1) - just use a hash implementation that gives you O(1) lookup time on average (C++ STL unordered_map for example). Assuming you are okay with the memory hit, this should be the most performant solution (performant in terms of execution time, not necessarily memory overhead).

Comment: What about another O(1) solution with a smaller constant?  That would be better...

Comment: Agree - that would indeed be faster and better - I was speaking asymptotically :).

Comment: "Speaking asymptotically" is not useful for a small bounded problem such as this.  In many problems, there can be solutions with larger big-O performance which are nevertheless faster for a problem of bounded size.  For instance, insertion sort generally outperforms O(n log n) sorts for small n.

Comment: Respectfully disagree - case in point: you used asymptotic complexity to give me an example where insertion sort outperforms more optimal comparison sorts with a complexity of O(nlogn). Why does that become important? Because its asymptotically better: O(n) as opposed to nlogn. The constant does matter. We would want to choose quicksort over other comparison sorts since for the most part, the constant in its performance is better. But asymptotic complexity is the first tool of choice when considering performance, after that it boils down to niche cases where you really care about the constant.

Comment: You've got it backwards.  Insertion sort is O(n^2), it beats quicksort's O(n log n) for small values of n because of the constants.  Asymptotics only enter the picture for large n.  Big-O notation does not give specific performance insights, and certainly not for small n.  Since this is a bounded size problem, big-O is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Yep - insertion sort is O(n-square). And you're right that for smaller values of n, the constants matter (I was suggesting it's almost linear time for small n). The bigger point I was making was that asymptotic perf is always going to be the first line of analysis - e.g. You wouldn't compare an O(n-square) algorithm with a small constant with an O(1) algorithm with a large constant. But my guess is that you already know this, so we're on the same page.

Comment: My point, again, is that since this is a problem of fixed size asymptotic analysis is not fruitful.  And yes, people **do** compare O(n^2) algorithms to O(1) algorithms quite frequently, to see where you might want to transition between them.  The best sorting algorithms, for instance, are hybrids which switch over to "worse" algorithms when the sub-problems get sufficiently small.